# Effective way for SQL

Tags: c#, sql, web-services

I have a project which we are thinking of optimizing some parts of the program.
It is basically a 3 tier hierarchy structure and below will be roughly how we structured.

UI - aspx and aspx.cs

Business Logic- Web Services

Data Access- a separate class residing the web service project.

Example:
The practice now is that when we retrieve data, we retrieve in terms of dataset from the web service and return it to the UI to process the displaying of data. In order to make changes to the database, the changed dataset is passed back to the web service. For small number of results, it would not pose much issue, but when the result is huge, web service will also be passing a larger xml to and forth, which greatly decrease performance.

So does anyone happen be using this type of structure and have a better way of processing database results? Right now, this practice is used in all CRUD, so the idea that came to me is for create and delete, or maybe even update, we can skip the passing of dataset, and use a linear command, but I am not sure is this a good method

Answer (score 3):

If by *dataset* you mean [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) then this is something that should never be passed to and from a web service. I would recommend you using POCO classes when communicating with the service. A DataSet already does XML serialization/deserialization internally and when you send it to a web service this serialization/deserialization will occur twice. Another tip is not to resend the entire dataset back to the web service but only what has changed in between the calls to reduce the network traffic.

Comment: I understand what U meant but this was the current structure of my coy, they are also intending to change, hence ask me to look through and give suggestion. Will POCO be able to work well with web service? I'm still finding information on POCO

Comment: I'm also considering the second option, but I need to explore the 2nd option to see if I can easily manipulate the 2 different datasets and merge them together. Honestly, I've been working with datareader mainly, only recently I have to go back to dataset

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: In web applications you should exchange only that data between client and server which is needed. I mean all filtering, etc should be done server side.

Some ideas are: Employ paging, avoid datasets, ask for only that information to your WS which you intend to show!

Comment: Yup, I know this, but the previous structure wasn't created by me, they employ dataset to make it easier to develop as they only need to pass around this dataset object and call update after the changes. What I need is something as working example that will allow me to do CRUD through webservice w/o much overhead